# Crosscorrelation for nonperiodic signals

Tags: functions, pattern-matching, convolution

I want to detect patterns (of an absorption spectrum which is nonperiodic) with Mathematica automaticly. I have found `CorrelationFuncion` but as far as I understand, it only does autocorrelation, not crosscorrelation. I also found `ListCorrelate` but it is similar to `ListConvolve` and doesn't truly detect patterns (see below).
My testdata is:

```
spec1=
Table[(PDF[NormalDistribution[50,1],x]+PDF[NormalDistribution[53,1],x])
+0.8(PDF[NormalDistribution[60,1],x]+PDF[NormalDistribution[63,1],x])
+0.7PDF[NormalDistribution[40,0.3],x]+3PDF[NormalDistribution[30,1.5],x]+
RandomReal[{-0.03,0.0.3}],{x,0,100,0.1}];
```

and

```
spec2=
Table[PDF[NormalDistribution[4,1],x]+PDF[NormalDistribution[7,1],x]
+RandomReal[{-0.03,0.0.3}],{x,0,15,0.1}];
```

-

```
ListLinePlot[{spec1,spec2},PlotRange->Full]
```

[image: testspectrum]

If I use `ListCorrelate`, the big peak at x=30 is the maximum, although the pattern at x=50 and x=60 correlate much better.

```
ListLinePlot[ListCorrelate[spec1,spec2,{-1,1},0],PlotRange->Full]
```

[image: Listcorrelate]

I guess this is because `Listcorrelate` doesn't normalize. Is there any way of getting the maximum for x=50 (2nd max for x=60)?